# Wordpress editor font

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

On the add/edit post screen, I don't have all the font sizes available. Can someone suggest how to enable a font size of e.g. 16pt ?
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6sbg.jpg)

I'm using TinyMCE Advanced.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the CSS of your child theme if you want to, in a custom CSS panel if your theme supports it or even directly inline in the WordPress editor but that is not highly suitable.

I read a bit and it seems to be a init file that handles all the custom font sizes and other font tweaks. it should be the: `tinymce.init`

Or follow this article:

https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?id=90661000000MrZkAAK

And this

https://support.tiny.cloud/hc/en-us/articles/226914348-Styling-font-sizes-in-TinyMCE

Comment: @Kamal Chopra if this helped and solved your question please do consider to check the answered checkbox on the left of my answer.